# Changing the color and enable to edit the value in the selected Row for Datagrid in C#

Tags: c#, datagrid

I am retrieving a table from SQL database and save it into a dataset.

After that I displayed that dataset on the form with DATAGRID.

I can show that.

Here comes my problem.

I have a column in the dataset.

Let's call it Status.

If the status is open, I want to change the font of that row and allow User to edit that row.

If not, User cannot edit it.

Anyone?

I have been searching a lot. But none of them really helped me.

I am using DATAGRID. NOT a gridview.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Use a datatemplate with datatriggers.

Comment: M i searching the wrong thing?
I dun see any datatemplate or datatriggers codes useful for my problem ?????